# How to dynamically modify view in ember RC3

Tags: ember.js

I have the following use case.
On server side error I would like to show to the user something went wrong (possibly allowing them to retry). I could either use a popup or status bar.
At the same time I want to keep the current view open i.e. the user should remain where the error happened.

I guess (please correct me if I am wrong) I should not use transitionTo(...) since this will replace my current view. My intention is rather to have a generic functionality in the application view (outer most template/view) which dynamically adds/removes the notification.

Design ideas how to construct and modify UI are very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this exact use case is simple. I have defined an event handler in my `ApplicationRoute` that gathers these exceptions and injects them into my custom `ExceptionsController` and `exceptions` is rendered somewhere into main application template.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        exceptionHandler: function (exception) {
            this.controllerFor('exceptions').addObject(exception);
        }
    }
});
```

`ExceptionsController` is just extension of `ArrayController`.

```
App.ExceptionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

Finally somewhere in my main application template I just use:

```
{{render 'exceptions'}}
```

I will leave the template to your imagination.

**EDIT**

Then if you want to raise an exception just use `send` to fire an action anywhere in your controller or route.

```
this.send('exceptionHandler', exception);
```

Where exception is your custom model.

Advantage of this solution is that you can override the handler in any other route below the application route or in any controller.